# Which is more flexible in regards to database changes, EF 4 or Linq to SQL

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2

Reading about both Linq to SQL and Entity Framework I have developed the impression that EF is more suitable for apps that get data from multiple data sources.

But as I am reading about MVC2 models I see an example where EF is more loosely coupled with your data model.

If I have to add or remove some columns from a table then what is involved in updating my model or DAL with each of these implementations?

Comment: This isn't really related to MVC though, data access layer and presentation layer tend to be fairly independent of each other.

Comment: I agree but I tagged the question MVC and ASP.Net hoping to get feedback from both the MVC crowd as well as the WebForms crowd as both can use the same data layer implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF4 is the way to go. The mappings are no longer completely volatile so you can refresh them with database changes instead of recreating them. Linq to SQL and EF1 are more volatile.